# How to add Google Analytics Event via PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-analytics

GA Events in Javascript we can do by

```
ga('send', 'event', 'test', 'test','value');
```

I need to implement this in entire project. But there are some sections where I need to do it via PHP.

So looking for PHP library that can be added as a module via composer.

I found

[Google Analytics Measurement Protocol library for PHP](http://%20https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol)

[PHP Analytics Events](https://github.com/there4/php-analytics-event)

But this one is not best. That which I'm looking for.

Tracking Id & Website only specified by once. Then just need to pass event parameters as we do in Javascript.

Does anyone come across any kind of this library?

Found this one very helpful

https://gearside.com/using-server-side-google-analytics-sending-pageviews-event-tracking/

Answer (score 2):

The Google analytics javascript snippet sends data to google analytics via the [measurment protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en)

The measurement protocol accepts http post and http gets.   This can easly be done with PHP but if you are looking for something out of the box created to do it there isnt anything official written in php that i am aware of.   Your going to have to code this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Using

https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-ga

Install via

```
composer require united-prototype/php-ga
```

Below is the code

```
  use UnitedPrototype\GoogleAnalytics; 

  $tracker = new GoogleAnalytics\Tracker('UA-XXXXXX-1', 'example.com');

  $session = new GoogleAnalytics\Session();

  // Setup visitor
  $visitor = new GoogleAnalytics\Visitor();
  $visitor->setIpAddress($server->get('REMOTE_ADDRESS'));
  $visitor->setUserAgent($server->get('HTTP_USER_AGENT'));

  //Set Event
  $event = new GoogleAnalytics\Event();
  $event->setCategory('Category'); // Event Category (Required)
  $event->setAction('Event'); // Event Action (Required)
  $event->setLabel('Label'); // Event Label (Optional)
  $event->setValue(1);    //integer, not required

  //track event
  $response = $tracker->trackEvent($event,$session,$visitor);
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: php-ga is no longer maintained as Google released an official server-side tracking API: Measurement Protocol